# Docker image not displayed for all local users

Tags: docker, active-directory, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been using the docker on windows for teaching and students use active directory to login to the non-admin users on the computers.

The issue is, I've pulled images in advance with the admin account, but when they run docker, it was nothing there.

Does anyone else has similar experience? I am thinking if this is because every user creates their own image folder when they run docker.

Comment: If your admin account is different to your user account, you must add the user to the docker-users group. Run Computer Management as an administrator and navigate to Local Users and Groups > Groups > docker-users. Right-click to add the user to the group. Log out and log back in for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to your local user in not added in the docker group and give the delegated control to read and write permission for other users.

Run Computer Management as an administrator and navigate to Local Users and Groups > Groups > docker-users. Right-click to add the user to the group. Log out and log back in for the changes to take effect.

You can refer this [Discussion](https://serverfault.com/questions/915206/how-to-allow-standard-non-admin-active-directory-users-access-to-docker-withou) how to allow access to active directory user to access the docker

Comment: Actually I have already added them into the docker-users, otherwise they wouldn't be able to start docker.